# Using if/else statement to insert a decimal for a column based on starting letter and string length of the row using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, stringr

I have a data frame "df" and want to apply if/else conditions to insert a decimal for the entire column "A"

```
A         B
E0505   123
890      43
4505     56
```

Rules to apply:

1. If the code starts with "E" and length of the code is > 4: between character 4 and 5.
2. If length of the code is > 3 and the code doesn't start with "E": between character 3 and 4.
3. If length of the code is <= 3: return the code as such.

Final output:

```
A          B
E050.5   123
890       43
450.5     56
```

I have tried this, but I am not sure how to include the condition where row starts with E or not.

```
ifelse(str_length(df$A)>3, as.character(paste0(substring(df$A, 1, 3),".", substring(df$A, 4))), as.character(df$A))
```

Comment: *"If length of the code is < 3: return the code as such"* I assume you mean `<= 3`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sub` with regular expression, you can do this:

```
df$A <- sub("((?:^E.|^[^E]).{2})(.+)", "\\1.\\2", df$A)

df
#       A   B
#1 E050.5 123
#2    890  43
#3  450.5  56
```

`((?:^E.|^[^E]).{2})(.+)` matches strings:

- case 1: starts with `E` followed by 4 or more characters, in which case capture the first 4 characters and the rest as two separate groups and insert `.` between;
- case 2: not starts with `E` but have 4 or more characters, in which case capture the first 3 characters and the rest as two separate groups and insert `.` between;

Strings starting with `E` and has less than 5 characters in total or not starting with `E` and has less than 4 characters in total are not matched, and will not be modified.

---

If ignoring case: `df$A <- sub("((?:^[Ee].|^[^Ee]).{2})(.+)", "\\1.\\2", df$A)`.

Comment: how do I implement/specify the condition where codes not starting with a letter "E". Specifically, I'd like to do this: If length of the code is > 3 and the code doesn't start with "E": between character 3 and 4. Thanks @Psidom

Comment: The case is included with the above regex. `E?.{3}` matches `E` optionally because of `?`, so if the code doesn't start with `E`, it matches 3 characters as the first group and insert `.` after.

Comment: One last question, I promise! @Psidom :) say I want to return the code as such if the length of the code starting with "E" is <=4. But apply the above rule for length of E code > 4.

Comment: IIUC. That case should also be covered by the regex. When the string starts with `E`, it matches `E` in the pattern first, and then because of `.{3})(.+)`, it at least has to have 4 other characters to insert `.`. Notice `.+` means match one or more characters.

Comment: For E<=4, it applies case 2. I tried this for eg @Psidom:
`b <- c("E0000","E000", "5676", "V567", "789", "12345")`
`sub("(E?.{3})(.+)", "\\1.\\2", b)`
`"E000.0" "E00.0"  "567.6"  "V56.7"  "789"    "123.45"`